# C# - increment number and keep zeros in front

Tags: c#, int, increment

I need to make a 40 digit counter variable. It should begin as `0000000000000000000000000000000000000001` 
and increment to 
`0000000000000000000000000000000000000002`

When I use the `int` class, it cuts off all the zeros. Problem is I need to increment the number and then convert it to a string, with the correct number of leading zeros. The total size should be 40 digits. So if I hit 50 for example, it should look like this:

`0000000000000000000000000000000000000050`

How can I do that and retain the zeros?

Comment: You'll be needing to use something more like [BigInteger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger.aspx) rather than `int`, otherwise the increment will fail in short order.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Use the integer and format or pad the result when you convert to a string. Such as

```
int i = 1;
string s = i.ToString().PadLeft(40, '0');
```

See [Jeppe Stig Nielson's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10935076/414076) for a formatting option that I can also never remember.

Comment: @RhysW, no, it simply pads to the length you specify with the character also specified. It will not exceed that length. For example, "123".PadLeft(2, '0') will simply return "123"

Answer (score 20):

Try using

```
int myNumber = ...;
string output = myNumber.ToString("D40");
```

Of course, the `int` can never grow so huge as to fill out all those digit places (the greatest `int` having only 10 digits).

Answer (score 2):

Just convert your string to int, perform the addition or any other operations, then convert back to string with adequate number of leading 0's:

```
// 39 zero's + "1"
string initValue = new String('0', 39) + "1";

// convert to int and add 1
int newValue = Int32.Parse(initValue) + 1;

// convert back to string with leading zero's
string newValueString = newValue.ToString().PadLeft(40, '0');
```

Answer (score 2):

I had to do something similar the other day, but I only needed two zeros. I ended up with

```
string str = String.Format("{0:00}", myInt);
```

Not sure if it's fool proof but try

```
String.Format("{0:0000000000000000000000000000000000000000}", myInt)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this too..

```
int number = 1;
string tempNumber = $"{number:00}";
```

result:

```
01
```