# how to increment 6digit value one by one

Tags: c#, asp.net

i have a variable say

```
             a=000000;
```

My requirement is when i loop this variable from 1 to 100 it will increment one by one ,like

```
    for loop 1 the value in 'a' will be 000001
    for loop 2 the value in 'a' will be 000002 like that
```

up to 100 it will be 000100.Any idea?

Comment: `a += 1`. Integers don't actually have leading zeroes though, that's a graphical representation, you have to handle that when you use the integer as a string.

Comment: or `a++;`, favorite way to increment

Comment: How you have something like `int a=000000`; It will anyway be `int a=0`;

Comment: I don't think a developer having almost 2 years of experience can ask a question like this.

Comment: foreach (int x in Enumerable.Range(1, 100)) Console.WriteLine(x.ToString("D6"))

Comment: @It'sNotALie.: put it as an answer and get an upvote if you want. ;-)

Comment: What you going to do within the loop? Do you need to store it or just print?

Comment: Have a look at [C# - increment number and keep zeros in front](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10935020/c-sharp-increment-number-and-keep-zeros-in-front)

Comment: @ranjenanil: Ok, answered !! Please try

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [PadLeft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/92h5dc07%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to format like that.

```
int intVariable = 0;
intVariable++; 
string output = intVariable.ToString().PadLeft(6, '0');
```

> A new string that is equivalent to this instance, but right-aligned
>   and padded on the left with as many paddingChar characters as needed
>   to create a length of totalWidth. However, if totalWidth is less than
>   the length of this instance, the method returns a reference to the
>   existing instance. If totalWidth is equal to the length of this
>   instance, the method returns a new string that is identical to this
>   instance, [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/92h5dc07%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

To generate in loop, you can use loop variable.

```
  for(int i=0; i < 100; i++)    
       output = i.ToString().PadLeft(6, '0');
```

Comment: when intVariable becomes 10,output will be 0000010 right?

Comment: Yes, it will be like that.

Comment: You can use `intVariable.ToString("D6")`.

Comment: I misread your first comment it wont go to 7 digit, it will be 000010 not 0000010

Answer (score 2):

Use `int`'s overload of `ToString` that takes a parameter and pass it the string D6:

```
foreach (int x in Enumerable.Range(1, 100)) 
    Console.WriteLine(x.ToString("D6"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like, this will keep always 6 digits

```
   for (int i = 1; i < 20; i++)
   {
      Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0:000000}", i));
   }
```

Comment: `WriteLine` already supports formatting, so use `Console.WriteLine("{0:000000}", i);`.

Comment: This is wrong. it only goes to 20. ;-) Just kidding. +1.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen: Sorry, I didn't get you? It is `Console.WriteLine`

Comment: I am saying you can remove the `String.Format( . . . )` part.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen: Oh yes, but seem OP using `asp.net` application. Probably he will not use `Console.WriteLine`